# Jquery not work but work after refresh

Tags: jquery

I have jquery issue on page. my click function not work when i go on web page but when i refresh page than click function working fine.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
        jQuery("#cart-var<?php echo $id; ?>").click(function(e){
            alert('hiii');
        });
    });
    });  // <--- Extra } and ) here!
</script>
```

Thanks,
vivek

Comment: `when i go on web page`? what you mean by this?

Comment: check if you are getting the `ID `when you go to the web page at first time?

Comment: Your function isn't working probably because some resource (script, css or image) still loading, so the load event is only fired when you hit refresh which causes all resources to stop loading. It causes the load event to be fired in the actual page.

Comment: Your code syntax is incorrect - you have one too many `});`

Comment: First try cleaning up your syntax, you have one extra }); than you need

Comment: Two issues i guess: i) you are not getting id when you go on web page ii) Incorrect syntax

Comment: Yup, as Darren and Rogi said, there is an extra `}` and `)`. I tried to do you a favor by indenting your code properly, and that jumped out at me immediately. Also note that where you have the `function($) {...`, you are not passing any argument into the function for the `$` parameter. This doesn't affect the code as written, because you aren't using `$` inside it. But if you just take the `$` out, that will be one less problem to worry about (since `jQuery` and `$` are the same by default).

Comment: @imaraan ahmad is right. what is the solution of this imraan

Comment: Sorry guys its not real code it's sample. my jquery not work but working well when i am refresh page

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this:

```
<?php if(!empty($id)): ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     
    jQuery("#cart-var<?php echo $id; ?>").click(function(e){
        alert('hiii');
    });
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```